# Does Main() accept expression?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

Why this code prints 1 instead of 5

Code:

```
main(int x=5) //this defn. is written intentionally to chec weather main accepts 
                expression or not. 
{
 printf("%d",x);  
}
```

Compiler used:minGW 3.2

**EDIT**

My point is weather `x=5` executes or not. if not then why i don't get any error or warning.

Comment: Oh my... you should really use one of the standard definitions of `main`, none of which use a single `int`, none of which has default values...

Comment: Note: This is an illegal declaration of main.

Comment: @All i'm doing this intentionally to check weather main execute expressions or not.

Comment: @Arpit: It's not a valid way to check that. Besides, what exception?

Comment: Default argument values are C++, not C.

Comment: @MSalters That was accept but i typed except :P

Comment: Please pick one language to tag; C and C++ are not the same language.

Comment: You can certainly declare a `main()` this way. However, this is *not* the `main()` function which is executed when your program starts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

because x is really argc (and your count of arguments is 1)

The signature for main is:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
```

with argc being a count of arguments 
and argv being an array of those arguments

Comment: so how can i print 5.(if its possible)

Comment: provide 4 command line arguments in addition to the name of your program `progname one two three four` will print 5.  Also, modify your function to properly implement main ()

Comment: @Arpit: Either call the program with enough arguments, or else... `printf("%d",5);`?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas i know i can do that in this way :). So my point is the expression `x=5` is executed or not.

Comment: @Arpit Of course it's not. You're making `argc` have a default value (of `5`) but `argc` is *always* passed to `main`. Your `5` will never get used.

Comment: @sftrabbit: Note that the signature in the OP is non-standard, so it is not guaranteed to even compile at all. @Arpit: Default values are used only at the caller side to fill in arguments they are not providing, but you cannot control who and how your `main` is called, that is part of the framework.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas  Thanks. i don't know that call to main is framework dependent. so its better never use this in any case.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Your `main` declaration is not valid, if we look at the [C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `3.6.1` *Main function* paragraph *2* says(*emphasis mine*):

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. **It shall have a return type of type int**, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. **All implementations shall allow both**
>
> > — a function of () returning int and
> >
> > — a function of (int, pointer to pointer to char) returning int

So `main` should adhere to one of these standard forms or *implementation defined* forms defined by compiler documentation.

`gcc` gives me a warning for this regardless of warning levels and in `clang` this is an error, so I am not sure why you do not see an error.

**Orignal Answer**

The first argument to main is the argument count usually denoted as argc for example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
}
```

and argv is an array of string which represents the arguments to your program, the first one being the command line.

Answer (score 1):

In `void f(int x = 5)`, the `= 5` part is a default argument. You can call the function in two different ways:

```
f();  // uses default argument, as if f(5)
f(3); // explicit argument
```

Note that the decision to use the default argument is made at the **point of the call**, not at the point of the declaration. Regardless of whether `int main(int x = 5, char *argv[])` is valid,  the application's startup code (part of the compiler's library) won't know about the attempted default argument, so won't do anything with it. And don't try and get tricky by calling `main` from inside your program: that's not allowed.

Answer (score -1):

Because the operating system expects this signature of `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv);
```

`argc` is the amount of parameters. When it calls your `main`, it passes the amount of arguments (`argc`) as the first parameter, which is 1 (if you call your binary without arguments, you still get one argument: the binary filename, `$0` in bash).

Note that this depends also on the C ABI. By the C/C++ standard, multiple signatures of `main` are allowed. So, depending on the compiler and the OS, there could be a different handling for `main`. What you are doing is not really defined behavior.

You should declare `main` like the expected - because that is what your OS expects and uses. Make another function for whatever you want to program.

Comment: So so... there are multiple valid signatures of `main`. All C++ implementations must support `int main()` and `int main(int,char**)`, and they might optionally take more arguments. This answer tries to fill a gap in knowledge but does not quite deliver.

Comment: Why is the first parameter necessarily 1?

Comment: @JBentley - I'm guessing that Albert is answering the OP (I'm also guessing that someone with a score of 7000+ doesn't think that argc is always one).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Well, sure. I don't quite see your point. The arguments are anyway on the stack. So when the OS calls `main`, you have the data inside your argument variables, if your signature specified any. That is why `x` gets 1, if the binary is started with argument count 1.

Comment: @Albert: There are quite a few assumptions there regarding the ABI, for example that the arguments are in the stack (which in x86_64 they are not), or that the order is such that the `int` will be in the same location (relative position to the stack frame) in `int x(int,char**)` and `int x(int)` which is not the case in all stack based ABIs... The `main` function is a very special function, and the implementation (compiler) must ensure that whatever the OS does ends up calling the right `main` with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: At any rate my comment was more in the lines of the last sentence being wrong... the OS does not expect `int main(int,char**)`, the implementation must adapt what the OS expects and what the language mandates, and the language allows for multiple different flavors of `main` (minimum set being `int main()`, `int main(int,char**)`) [I did not downvote, but that is the reason I did not upvote either]

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: In any C ABI I know, `int main()` or `int main(int,char**)` (or any other...) would end up as the same symbol. The OS cannot really know which one you used, so it would just put the symbols on the stack - that is what I thought. Of course, there might be some additional special handling for `main` by the compiler.

Comment: @Albert: The real entry point to the program is not `main`. There are many things that happen before `main` is reached. For example, objects with static storage duration are initialized. The entry point from the OS is directed to the code that performs all those pre-main operations. After that completes, `main` is called. The real call to the `main` function is triggered from within the compiler code, not the OS.